# How do I redirect only stderr?

Tags: bash, compiling, io-redirection

I am having a bit of trouble doing this. I am required to run a compiled .java file and redirect only stderr to a file called error. So the .java file is named javaProgram.java.

This is what I have tried:

```
java javaProgram 2> error
```

However when I

```
cat error
```

it appears that there is stuff in there, even when I know for a fact that the specific .java file has no errors. Am I doing something wrong? All I want this error file to display is errors, not anything else.

Answer (score 27):

Your first try was correct; `2>filename` is how you redirect stderr. It may be the case that your program is writing some non-errors to stderr, or the java program is running other programs that output to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that it isn't possible. Standard error is used for writing diagnostic output and it's up to the applications to define what is diagnostic/error output. That's according to the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/).

Comment: If you are going to cite the POSIX spec, please cite a specific section and not the entire document. It's huge.

Comment: Since when is it not possible to redirect stderr to file in POSIX? You'll have to provide an actual quote for that.

Comment: @l0b0 that isn't what Jeight is saying. It's up to applications to decide what goes to STDOUT and what goes to STDERR; it would be entirely possible to shove everything into STDOUT, for example, and then redirecting STDERR would have no effect. Or, as in this case, it's possible (and standard practice) to put some things that aren't strictly errors into STDERR. The only way it would be possible to parse the errors from other diagnostics would be if the errors are marked with 'ERROR:' or something. There may be a verbosity switch that could help, but that's program-specific.

Comment: OP posed two semantically different problems: "redirect only stderr to a file called error" and "I want this error file to display is errors, not anything else." The first part of that certainly isn't impossible, is my point.

Comment: @l0b0 You've got it backwards. The OP definitely can redirect the stderr to a file called error. He can not choose what Java  outputs as stderr because the content of stderr is controlled by the application and not the user. What he can do is grep the file that stderr was passed to for actual error messages.